# Formatting a file using awk

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have  a file in following from

```
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
adornment adorn:stem<>ment:suffix
advertisement advertise:stem<>ment:suffix
aggravation aggravate:stem<>ion:suffix
aggregation aggregate:stem<>ion:suffix
agreeable agree:stem<>able:suffix
```

I need to convert it to following form

```
(adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
(addiction ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
(adornment ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
(advertisement ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
(aggravation ((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix)))
(aggregation (aggregate:stem)ion:suffix))
(agreeable ((agree:stem)able:suffix))
where most complex ones are 
(imperialistic (((imperialism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix))
```

I tried to do it using awk.
This is the code, I used awk `'{print $0")"}' restof120.txt by executing the command it added`)` at the end of all the line.

```
awk '{print "("$0")"}'
```

My question is there any way to automatically convert the format? Using any package.

There are complex case
Examples

```
 indecipherable in:prefix<>decipher:stem<>able:suffix
 (indecipherable (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix))
```

Update: some patterns, I have seen

```
 inactive in:prefix<>active:stem
    (inactive ((in:prefix)active:stem))
```

Comment: Your input doesn't match your output - there are 4 additional lines in your output.

Comment: What is the input for _altruistic_ , which is the most complex case; are there any more complex than this ?

Comment: There are imperialistic imperialism:stem)ist:suffix)ic:suffix

Comment: Can you add an input example for the complex case?

Comment: Come on, just give us one block of sample input and the expected output given that input - don't spread it all over your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you're looking for:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    n = gsub(/<>|$/,")",$2)
    s = sprintf("%*s",n,"")
    gsub(/ /,"(",s)
    print "(" $1, s $2 ")"
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
(adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
(addiction ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
(adornment ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
(advertisement ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
(aggravation ((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix))
(aggregation ((aggregate:stem)ion:suffix))
(agreeable ((agree:stem)able:suffix))
(indecipherable (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix))
```

Comment: The number of brackets must match

Comment: Do you see a line where they don't?

Answer (score 2):

Following the edit with the complex case, I would modify my sed command to use loops :

```
sed -r -e ':loop' -e 's/([^ ]+)<>/(\1)/' -e 't loop' -e 's/(.* )(.*)/(\1 (\2))/'
```

It will replace from the right and carry on until the replace fails to match anything, so the replacement for the "indecipherable" test case will go as follows :

```
indecipherable in:prefix<>decipher:stem<>able:suffix     # original text
indecipherable (in:prefix<>decipher:stem)able:suffix     # after 1st iteration
indecipherable ((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix     # after 2nd iteration
(indecipherable (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix)) # after loop: add the outer parentheses
```

> Test run :
>
> ```
> $ echo """adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
> addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
> adornment adorn:stem<>ment:suffix
> advertisement advertise:stem<>ment:suffix
> aggravation aggravate:stem<>ion:suffix
> aggregation aggregate:stem<>ion:suffix
> agreeable agree:stem<>able:suffix
> indecipherable in:prefix<>decipher:stem<>able:suffix""" | sed -r -e ':loop' -e 's/([^ ]+)<>/(\1)/' -e 't loop' -e 's/(.* )(.*)/(\1 (\2))/'
> (adaptable  ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
> (addiction  ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
> (adornment  ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
> (advertisement  ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
> (aggravation  ((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix))
> (aggregation  ((aggregate:stem)ion:suffix))
> (agreeable  ((agree:stem)able:suffix))
> (indecipherable  (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix))
> ```

---

I would use the following sed command :

```
sed -r 's/(\w+) (\w+:stem)<>(\w+:suffix)/(\1 ((\2)\3))/'
```

> Example :
>
> ```
> $ echo """adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
> addiction addict:stem<>ion:suffix
> adornment adorn:stem<>ment:suffix
> advertisement advertise:stem<>ment:suffix
> aggravation aggravate:stem<>ion:suffix
> aggregation aggregate:stem<>ion:suffix
> agreeable agree:stem<>able:suffix""" | sed -r 's/(\w+) (\w+:stem)<>(\w+:suffix)/(\1 ((\2)\3))/'
> (adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
> (addiction ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
> (adornment ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
> (advertisement ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
> (aggravation ((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix))
> (aggregation ((aggregate:stem)ion:suffix))
> (agreeable ((agree:stem)able:suffix))
> ```

Comment: For the complex case, the loop works great. Change to `s/(.* )(.*)/(\1 (\2))/`  for the final command, as you're missing a set of parentheses around the last word. The "inner" replacement can be simplified to `s/([^ ]+)<>/(\1)/`

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F'[ <>]' '{print "(" $1, "((" $2 ")" $4 "))" }' file

(adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
(addiction ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
(adornment ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
(advertisement ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
(aggravation ((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix))
(aggregation ((aggregate:stem)ion:suffix))
(agreeable ((agree:stem)able:suffix))
```

for the extra case, it's better to delegate to a function instead of manually putting the parenthesis

```
$ awk -F'[ <>]' 'function wrap(a) {return "("a")"}; 
       {w=wrap(wrap($2)$4)} 
   NF>5{w=wrap(w$6)} 
       {print wrap($1" "w)}' file_with_complex_case

(adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
(addiction ((addict:stem)ion:suffix))
(adornment ((adorn:stem)ment:suffix))
(advertisement ((advertise:stem)ment:suffix))
(aggravation (((aggravate:stem)ion:suffix)))
(aggregation (((aggregate:stem)ion:suffix)))
(agreeable (((agree:stem)able:suffix)))
(indecipherable (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix))
```

Comment: This perfectly worked for  simple ones but failed in the case of ccomplex ones   narcissistic narcissism:stem<>ist:suffix<>ic:suffix

Comment: Please update that case in your original post.  I don't see it so can't verify.

Comment: I have up dated the complex case

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -F ' |<>' '{
    parts = ""
    for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) parts = "(" parts $i ")"
    print "(" $1, parts ")"
}' <<END
adaptable adapt:stem<>able:suffix
indecipherable in:prefix<>decipher:stem<>able:suffix
END
```

```
(adaptable ((adapt:stem)able:suffix))
(indecipherable (((in:prefix)decipher:stem)able:suffix))
```

It's using space or the string `<>` as the field separator (may require GNU awk). It accumulates the parts to wrap in parentheses.

Comment: It doesn't require GNU awk, all awks support an RE for FS, it's just when you want an RE for RS that you need gawk.